# How does head connected to tail when deleting the list

Tags: c, struct

I have a function which creates a list based on a given array,
this is the function:

```
typedef struct Item
{
    int num;
    struct Item* next;
}*PItem;

int main()
{
    int Arr[N] = { 3, 4, 1, 0, 8 }, i;

    PItem list = NULL, tail = NULL;

    CreateListFromArray(&list, &tail, Arr);
}
void CreateListFromArray(PItem* head, PItem* tail, int *Arr)
{
    int i;
    PItem temp;
    for (i = 0; i<N; i++)
    {
        temp = (PItem)malloc(sizeof(struct Item));
        if (temp == NULL)
        {
            DeleteList(head);
            Error_Msg("Memmory!");
        }
        temp->num = Arr[i];
        temp->next = NULL;
        if (*head == NULL)
            *head = temp;
        else
            (*tail)->next = temp;
        *tail = temp;
    }
}
```

I understand that if List is empty, then head's null is initialized to the first allocated temp (`arr[0]`). But after that, for these arrays `arr[1],..,arr[N]`, I update only the tail, meaning that all the tails from `arr[1]` to `arr[N]` are connected. but how does the head (`arr[0]`) POINTS/connected to `arr[1]`?

I ask this because, when I try to print the list, I use `temp = head`, and advance head until temp is null, but when I advance head, how does it know that it has to advance to `arr[1]`?

**Here's the full code:** http://pastebin.com/VPCfMU4X

Comment: `int Arr[N] = { 3, 4, 1, 0, 8 },` this doesn't seem correct .

Comment: _"head's null is initialized to the first allocated temp"_ What does this mean?

Comment: @ameyCU actually `int Arr[N] = { 3, 4, 1, 0, 8 }, i;` is correct even if it looks strange.

Comment: @ameyCU: Regardless, it is! Though that `i` declaration is entirely redundant.

Comment: I've uploaded the whole code, you can run and test that it works. I just don't understand how there is a connection between head's node and the other nodes.

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS your code on pastebin lacks the `ListDisplay` function.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That means, that the first node is initialized to be the head.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I have not written that function yet

Comment: I really don't understand. First iteration `if (*head == NULL) *head = temp;` set the head to the `Arr[0].` What is your doubt?

Comment: You wrote this code, forgot how it works and now cannot run it under a debugger to find out?

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS ... well then don't claim that it runs.

Comment: @MartinJames I didn't write the code, I wrote just the last recursive function.

Comment: BTW `arr[1],..,arr[N]` --> `arr[1],..,arr[N-1]`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY That's true :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the first iteration of the loop, `head` and `tail` point to the same element which contains `arr[0]`.  After the second iteration, `(*tail)->next` (which is the same as `(*head)->next`) point to the new element that contains `arr[1]`, and `tail` is moved up to this value.  Subsequent iterations keep appending to the end of the list.

So after one iteration, you have this:

```
head      tail
  |         |
  v         v
---------------
|  3 |  NULL  |
---------------
```

After the second iteration, you have this:

```
head                     tail
  |                       |
  v                       v
---------------    ---------------
|  3 |  .-----|--->|  4 |  NULL  |
---------------    ---------------
```

And the third:

```
head                                       tail
  |                                          |
  v                                          v
---------------    ---------------    ---------------
|  3 |  .-----|--->|  4 |  .-----|--->|  1 |  NULL  |
---------------    ---------------    ---------------
```

Comment: Thank you very much dbush. Quick question, in the second iteration head's and tail's next are the same because they both point on the same structure?

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS Correct.  If two pointers point to the same place (i.e. have the same value), then dereferencing either of them will give you the exact same thing.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your time and explanation. That was really helpful!